# Rails - How to organize constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some constants that I want to define globally in my applications. Also, these constants don't belong to any model. What's the best practice to organize those constants.

Any advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Use concerns folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple you can define Module called as example `Constants` and define it inside the module

```
module Constants
  CONST1="value"
  CONST2="value2"
end
```

it's possible also to group them like

```
 module Constants
  module Group1
    CONST1="value"
    CONST2="value2"
  end
  module Group2
   # some relevant constants 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks. In your point of view, where should I place the code / file?

Comment: you can place it in lib/ . the lib dir is always the place for any kind of custom code that doesn’t belong under controllers, models, or helpers

Comment: In my opinion putting constants in lib is not a good idea. I agree with iGian's comment above, to put in concerns folder. But your answer is worth

Comment: Concerns are only for models or controllers . and you told that you need these constants like globals so you can use it inside services and libraries not only in models and concerns folder is for concerns only I don't expect to find Generic Constants in it when I check any source code but these design decisions are always hard to be 100% right or wrong .

Comment: Yah. Thanks for explaining your thoughts. I see there are `assets` and `tasks` in `lib` folder. I think we won't put constants in those folders, will we? And another point is `lib` is not auto loaded by Rails, create an application config to load it seems not correct

Comment: when you work in a large project you will find the lib folder used heavily, check a well known open source project like gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/lib i worked also in large projects like testerwork and instabug and the same

Comment: Well, You persuaded me. Thanks Elkady